# How to find all available properties and methods of a gradle plugin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

Is there a way to find all available properties and methods of a Gradle Plugin, or does it purely rely on documentation?

Am I missing a Gradle command or window in Android Studio that shows me all available options? Without it I would practically have to guess...

In this particular case I'm looking for more information on the Firebase Crashlytics Gradle Plugin.

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle
```

**Edit**

To make myself more clear, in the following example taken from [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_8) how would I find out which methods I can use within the `firebaseCrashlytics` block.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    // ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                // If you don't need crash reporting for your debug build,
                // you can speed up your build by disabling mapping file uploading.
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            // When minifyEnabled is set to true, Crashlytics automatically
            // uploads mapping files because the plugin detects that obfuscation
            // is enabled. mappingFileUploadEnabled defaults to true if
            // minifyEnabled is true.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about a command like that in AS, but what specific information are you looking for?

Comment: @OlegKodysh I'm searching for what kind of methods are available for a specific Gradle plugin. I just noticed if I do cmd + click on a method it guides me to the extensions class, and I can see all available methods there. But if I didn't know anything about the plugin, how would I know which class to search for in my project?

Comment: Yea, once again, not sure in a general sense, but here's what I think you're looking for on the Crashlytics side https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/crashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics

Comment: @OlegKodysh I've updated the question with an example to make it more clear.

Comment: Gotcha. Yea that link I commented above does detail which calls the Firebase Crashlytics SDK gives you access to.

Comment: @OlegKodysh I can't find these gradle methods in the link you provided. That's the documentation for the Firebase Crashlytics SDK, and I'm looking for a way to find out more about the crashlytics gradle plugin (or any other gradle plugin).

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```
./gradlew tasks
```

It should provide you with a list of different tasks.